# Complex integral parametrization independence

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if anyone could explain where in the standard change of variables proof that a complex line integral is independent of parametrization does one require that the change of variables function have non-negative derivative. I've seen this requirement both in Newman and Stein texts but can't seem to think of any rationalization. It seems that even if the parametrization equivalence functions changed signs but eventually traveled the correct path, you would get additive factors of opposite signs that would cancel out, so I'm wondering if the derivative requirement for curve equivalence only becomes relevant in other contexts in complex analysis.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but that condition is almost equivalent to the injectivity of the change of parametrization plus preserving the direction you travel the curve, which really makes sense to ask for a change of parametrization. But, the theorem could indeed be stated in more generality, altough I think it is not necessary.

Comment: Right, I noticed the connection to the general statements of the change of variables theorem although can you think of a pathological example that shows you need "some regularity condition" if not a non-negative derivative?

Comment: Or I should say maybe a one dimensional integral pathological example.

Comment: Maybe I thought of one - can you take a monotonic continuous function with zero derivative almost everywhere, e.g. a cantor function, to reason that the change of variables will give you zero?

Comment: I don't think that example is useful because for the change of variables theorem you need the "change of variable function" to be differentiable everywhere and Cantor function is not. At least, I have never seen a version of change of variable theorem where the function isn't at least, differentiable.

Comment: Right, my question is mostly what the continuous differentiability condition, along with 1-1 property and non-negative derivative is trying to pre-empt (and also, is there some redundancy/non-necessary condition there)? Newman's statement requires all three conditions, although it seems clear you can drop 1-1. Newman assumes orientation is the same by fixing parametrizations end-points btw.

Comment: Maybe Newman's statement is a bit redundant. Here is the same result as stated in Ash, Complex Variables, that maybe is more clear about your doubts: Let $\gamma: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a piecewise continuously differentiable function (which is called a path), $f$ a complex function continuous on the image of $\gamma$ and $h:[c,d] \longrightarrow [a,b]$ a 1-1 continuously differentiable function with $h(c)=a$ and $h(d)=b$. Then, $\gamma_1=\gamma \circ h$ is a path and $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz = \int_\gamma f(z) dz$

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. Will keep open for other observations from people but I think maybe part of the point is to make sure the change of variables produces a "path" as defined in each text (ie if a path is 1-1, then the change of variables cannot integrate over a non-path since it is not a defined concept).